# voltage suffixes meaning

Tags: schematics, naming-conventions

I came across the following schematics on a TV main board.

[image]

And a bit lower

[image]

I try to understand the meaning of the name of different rails.
I suspect that  `STB` means standby.

Does the following notations refers to some kind of standard notations ?

`_M`, `_AUDAC`, `_EMMC`, `_STBC`, `_M_SIFADC`, `M_TVADC`

Same question for the non prefix `CORE`

Full schematics can be found here https://www.electronica-pt.com/esquema/func-fileinfo/83341/

Comment: No, they’res no standard for these names - you have to figure them out by context. Audac is probably audio digital to analog converter, emmc is probably the flash storage device, stbc probably standby controller, core is the cpu core, m is probably memory, sifadc is some sort of adc etc.

Comment: The names are specific to that chip or that board. We can only guess their purpose without knowing the chip data sheet, but e.g. XTAL could be for crystal oscillator and all the interfaces may have their own supply pin to select the voltage used for that interface.

Comment: Those names are whatever the drawer of the schematic (usually the designer) decided to use.  Their meaning is probably crystal clear to the designer, not so much to a 3rd party.

Comment: Note that depending on the tool and when that schematic was created, there may have been a limitation on how many characters could be in a signal name.  Some of the early EDA tools restricted you to 12 or 16 characters, which led to some rather creative signal names.